# App update with support of iPhone 5 and white strip issue

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, updates, iphone-5, strip

I have an existing app I had to update, and I decided to support iPhone 5 on it.
To do that, I made a new splashscreen and checked all my xibs to fit the new size.

As the update is released, I wanted to check it.
But when I update my already installed app, I have a large white strip at the bottom my iPhone 4:
[image: Already installed app and then updated, on iPhone 4]

For a  newly installed app on iPhone  4 or 5 it's ok, the tabBar is at the bottom of the screen.

Except this white strip, the app is entirely functional.

The tabBarController is defined in my MainWindow.xib:
[image: tabBarController definition]

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Autolayout in interface builder (Under File Inspector)? I was having similar issues with my app when I updated it to support the iPhone 5. Performing a clean install did the trick for me but similarly that wouldn't work for pre-existing users. Unselect this option and Use the size inspector to align objects (and/or) resize them using autosizing.

Comment: I'm not using AutoLayout cause I need the app to be compatible with ios 5.1.